# SQL Server 2008 R2: Combine two queries for optimization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query to optimize.

Following used to get the details from the profit table.

- First inner SELECT: in the first select statement I have to get the details from the profit table and assign the row number for each row.
- Second inner SELECT: in the second select statement I have to do some calculation (sum).
- Outer SELECT: And get the result by combining them on id and also do some manipulation with data.

Code:

```
SELECT  
    a.p_id, p_Name,
    convert(varchar, a.EndDate, 107) EndDate,
    convert(varchar, a.EndDate, 106) NewEndDate,
    LTRIM(a.p_id)) + '' + REPLACE(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.EndDate, 106), 6) + '' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.EndDate, 106), 2), ' ', '') as Compo,
    a.GP,           
    b.fpro FirstProfit,
    (b.fpro - b.spro) prodiff,
    a.Qtity * a.GP as Ov,
    a.Qtity,
    b.fproChanPer
FROM
    (SELECT 
         p_Name, p_id,
         EndDate,
         GP, FirstProfit,
         prodiff,
         Qtity,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By p_Name, p_id ORDER BY EndDate) Rown
     FROM   
         tbl_profit) a,
    (SELECT 
         p_id, 
         CAST(SUM(FirstProfit) AS DECIMAL(24,2)) fpro,
         CAST(SUM(SecondProfit) AS DECIMAL(24,2)) spro,
         CAST(CAST(SUM(prodiff) AS DECIMAL(24,2)) / CAST(SUM(SecondProfit) AS DECIMAL(24,2)) * 100 AS DECIMAL(24,2)) fproChanPer
     FROM 
         tbl_profit
     GROUP BY
         p_id) b    
WHERE 
    b.p_id = a.p_id 
    AND Rown = 1
```

My question: can I combine those two (alias `a` and `b`) inner SELECT statements for query optimization?

My attempt: I have tried by using the following query **but** getting different calculation result.

```
    SELECT  p_Name,
            p_id,
            EndDate,
            GP,
            FirstProfit,
            prodiff,
            Qtity
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION By p_Name,p_id ORDER By EndDate ) Rown,
            CAST(SUM(FirstProfit) AS DECIMAL(24,2)) fpro,
            CAST(SUM(SecondProfit) AS DECIMAL(24,2)) spro,
            CAST(CAST(SUM(prodiff) AS DECIMAL(24,2)) /CAST(SUM(SecondProfit) AS DECIMAL(24,2)) * 100 AS DECIMAL(24,2)) fproChanPer
    FROM    tbl_profit
    GROUP By p_id,p_Name,EndDate,GP,FirstProfit,prodiff,Qtity
```

Comment: Not sure if Sql server 2008 supports `SUM() OVER()`, but if it does, you can use a single inner select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tbl_profit must have multiple P_Name for a single p_id , when you are grouping by p_id only you are getting correct aggregate value whereas because of multiple p_name for a single p_id when you are grouping by p_id and p_name your aggregate sum values are getting double for wherever single p_id has more than one p_name.

The way you written query to get Rown = 1 records in this case is perfect, thought still have scope to optimize I have done few things please check.

```
SELECT
     a.p_id,
     p_Name,
     CONVERT(varchar, a.EndDate, 107) EndDate,
     CONVERT(varchar, a.EndDate, 106) NewEndDate,
     LTRIM(a.p_id) + '' + REPLACE(LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, a.EndDate, 106), 6) + '' + RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, a.EndDate, 106), 2), ' ', '') AS Compo,
     a.GP,
     b.fpro AS FirstProfit,
     (b.fpro - b.spro) prodiff,
     a.Qtity * a.GP AS Ov,
     a.Qtity,
     b.fproChanPer
FROM (
    SELECT
         a.p_Name,
         a.p_id,
         a.EndDate,
         a.GP,
         a.FirstProfit,
         a.prodiff,
         a.Qtity,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.p_Name, a.p_id ORDER BY a.EndDate) Rown
    FROM tbl_profit AS a WITH (NOLOCK)
    ) AS a
INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT
         b.p_id,
         CAST(SUM(b.FirstProfit) AS decimal(24, 2)) fpro,
         CAST(SUM(b.SecondProfit) AS decimal(24, 2)) spro,
         CAST(CAST(SUM(b.prodiff) AS decimal(24, 2)) / CAST(SUM(b.SecondProfit) AS decimal(24, 2)) * 100 AS decimal(24, 2)) fproChanPer
    FROM tbl_profit AS b WITH (NOLOCK)
    GROUP BY b.p_id
    ) AS b
ON b.p_id = a.p_id
     AND a.Rown = 1
```